# In PHP fopen function， what's the difference between w and w+ mode?

Tags: php

I have read the manaul, and knew that w+ write and read, w only write. But how to understand it?

```
$file_name =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../data/test.txt";  //file is exist
$fp = fopen($file_name, 'w+');
fwrite($fp, 'hello, world!');
$len = filesize($file_name); 
echo $len; //13
$contents = fread($fp, $len);
var_dump($contents);//string(0) ""    why?
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: @C.Ricky I think you already do, try not to over think it

Comment: In short, use "w" if you only use `fwrite` and "w+" if you use both `fread` and `fwrite`

Comment: @Vincent  I just cannot understand why the manual told that w+ can read, But I wrote a example, it can't.  I use fopen("file_address", w+)   and use fwrite put something in it,  then try to use fread get the things, but it return null. I change w+ to r, It works.

Comment: It's important to note that both "w+" and "w" will clear the existing file contents if any so I suppose "w+" would be useful if you wanted to write things and then go back to read those same things again in the same run.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks a lot.  " use "w" if you only use fwrite and "w+" if you use both fread and fwrite"~

Comment: @apokryfos I have tried what you said, and add the code to the question's describtion, can you help me find what's wrong with that code?

Comment: @C.Ricky You need to rewind your file stream back to the start before you can read i.e. `rewind($fp)` or if you want to jump to a specific location use `fseek`. This is because `fread` reads from the current position in the file which is the end of the file (since you just wrote to it).

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks very much, I got the reason with your help, It really works, haha..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both options **w** and **w+** truncates file during opening with fopen. Difference is that you can read exactly that was written during current session working with file(I mean fopen->fwrite->fread(will not empty)->fclose). So if you try to read file opened with **w** and **w+** = the result in both case should be empty